# Clear SMSs through API?

Tags: android, permissions, sms, android-developer-api

Is there any way to clear or delete previous texts sent from an app through some sort of permission?

I recognize that this might present a security issue but I'm hoping it would just be for the particular thread of texts from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  You can delete whatever you want from the SMS database-  if you're the default SMS app.  What app is the default SMS app is settable by the user, but not settable programatically.  Outside of that there is no access to write that db.